# Compile PJSIP example

Tags: gcc, makefile, compiler-errors, pjsip

I am trying to compile a PJSIP example following [this tutorial](https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting_Started_Using), but I have those errors after `make`:

```
cc     simple_pjsua.c   -o simple_pjsua
/tmp/ccxmvFQD.o: In function `on_incoming_call':
simple_pjsua.c:(.text+0x40): undefined reference to `pjsua_call_get_info'
simple_pjsua.c:(.text+0x45): undefined reference to `pj_log_get_level'
simple_pjsua.c:(.text+0x6f): undefined reference to `pj_log_3'
simple_pjsua.c:(.text+0x8b): undefined reference to `pjsua_call_answer'
/tmp/ccxmvFQD.o: In function `on_call_state':
simple_pjsua.c:(.text+0xe0): undefined reference to `pjsua_call_get_info'
simple_pjsua.c:(.text+0xe5): undefined reference to `pj_log_get_level'
simple_pjsua.c:(.text+0x119): undefined reference to `pj_log_3'
/tmp/ccxmvFQD.o: In function `on_call_media_state':
simple_pjsua.c:(.text+0x167): undefined reference to `pjsua_call_get_info'
simple_pjsua.c:(.text+0x184): undefined reference to `pjsua_conf_connect'
simple_pjsua.c:(.text+0x196): undefined reference to `pjsua_conf_connect'
/tmp/ccxmvFQD.o: In function `error_exit':
simple_pjsua.c:(.text+0x1d0): undefined reference to `pjsua_perror'
simple_pjsua.c:(.text+0x1d5): undefined reference to `pjsua_destroy'
/tmp/ccxmvFQD.o: In function `main':
simple_pjsua.c:(.text+0x20b): undefined reference to `pjsua_create'
simple_pjsua.c:(.text+0x24b): undefined reference to `pjsua_verify_url'
simple_pjsua.c:(.text+0x27b): undefined reference to `pjsua_config_default'
simple_pjsua.c:(.text+0x2ab): undefined reference to `pjsua_logging_config_default'
simple_pjsua.c:(.text+0x2d3): undefined reference to `pjsua_init'
simple_pjsua.c:(.text+0x303): undefined reference to `pjsua_transport_config_default'
simple_pjsua.c:(.text+0x326): undefined reference to `pjsua_transport_create'
simple_pjsua.c:(.text+0x34c): undefined reference to `pjsua_start'
simple_pjsua.c:(.text+0x37c): undefined reference to `pjsua_acc_config_default'
simple_pjsua.c:(.text+0x386): undefined reference to `pj_str'
simple_pjsua.c:(.text+0x39e): undefined reference to `pj_str'
simple_pjsua.c:(.text+0x3c0): undefined reference to `pj_str'
simple_pjsua.c:(.text+0x3d8): undefined reference to `pj_str'
simple_pjsua.c:(.text+0x3f0): undefined reference to `pj_str'
/tmp/ccxmvFQD.o:simple_pjsua.c:(.text+0x412): more undefined references to `pj_str' follow
/tmp/ccxmvFQD.o: In function `main':
simple_pjsua.c:(.text+0x43b): undefined reference to `pjsua_acc_add'
simple_pjsua.c:(.text+0x47b): undefined reference to `pj_str'
simple_pjsua.c:(.text+0x4b3): undefined reference to `pjsua_call_make_call'
simple_pjsua.c:(.text+0x51c): undefined reference to `pjsua_call_hangup_all'
simple_pjsua.c:(.text+0x524): undefined reference to `pjsua_destroy'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
<builtin>: recipe for target 'simple_pjsua' failed
make: *** [simple_pjsua] Error 1
```

Of course I did `$ ./configure && make dep && make && make install`. And if I search for the libpjproject lib I can find it here :

```
/usr$ find -iname "*libpjproject*"
./local/lib/pkgconfig/libpjproject.pc
```

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the error.. I made a mistake in the Makefile.
Not working :

```
# If your application is in a file named myapp.cpp or myapp.c
# this is the line you will need to build the binary.
all: simple_pjsua

myapp : simple_pjsua.c
    $(CC) -o $@ $< `pkg-config --cflags --libs libpjproject`

clean:
    rm -f simple_pjsua.o simple_pjsua
```

Working :

```
# If your application is in a file named myapp.cpp or myapp.c
# this is the line you will need to build the binary.
all: simple_pjsua

simple_pjsua: simple_pjsua.c
    $(CC) -o $@ $< `pkg-config --cflags --libs libpjproject`

clean:
    rm -f simple_pjsua.o simple_pjsua
```

I forgot to change `myapp : simple_pjsua.c` to `simple_pjsua: simple_pjsua.c`